# How to increase the distance of one element from another as the width gets smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website with **HTML/CSS/JS** and encountered a problem.
On the front page, I have a image and a text over the image, the image has a 100% width and a fixed height of 487px, I set the text to `position:relative;` and `top:34vh`.

When the website is on the normal desktop size, it looks as it should,but when I try to make it responsive, as the width gets smaller the text, as it should, gets smaller too, and its position alternes. What I want is to have the text sticky to the bottom side of the image.

I will present an example of how it looks and how would I want it to look like.

**Thank you in advance!**

[image]

Comment: if it has a fixed height, the you shouldn't use `vh` for your `top` as that is relative to the screen height

Comment: yes, I figured that, but I do not know what to use

Comment: why not use `bottom: -1em` or however much you want it to poke out of the bottom

Comment: @Pete I would still have to use media queries, no?

Answer (score 1):

Media queries.

I'll go something like this:

```css
.element {
  margin-top: 50vh
}
@media only screen and (min-width 500px) {
  .element {
    margin-top: 90vh
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width 1000px) {
  .element {
    margin-top: 90vh
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that would be a possibility, though I am still looking for something else as this method is not really the user-friendlier one.

Answer (score 0):

So I  have used `bottom: 2 em;`.
Thanks @Pete for the answer in the comments.

Comment: Please don't post comments in the answers space. You will be able to comment once you have 50 reputation.